# Review close reason

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

This question (not mine) was voted closed today based on a duplicate :

[Should "Deletion successful" confirmation be red, or green?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74959/should-deletion-successful-confirmation-be-red-or-green)

this question I think is quite different from the duplicates, because one deals with active buttons, and the other deals with a notification. They are very different UX components with correspondingly different design objectives.

For example, Google material design has totally different interactions, style, animations, and behavior for the two:

[image]

For this reason, I don't think it's a duplicate question at all

Comment: I agree. Voted to reopen (note that that is a feature...if you think a question should be reopened, vote for it. )